Preparing data for LTSM with multiple features and uncorrelated target ends up in predicting mean value
I am trying to predict micro-weather events, such as the expected temperature in the next hour, by using an LTSM for a regression. It's an exercise in LTSM.
The data:
I have a CSV with 10000 samples (rows).
Each row has a timestamp and 3 features
(X's): datetime, altitude, humidity, pressure
And the label
(Y's): datetime, temperature
My theory is that after I train an LTSM model enough samples, it should be able to predict the temperature of the next hour, but I am NOT using the temperature as a feature, just as a label.
This is how a single sample is organized to the LTSM model (using Pytorch):
[altitude (t),humidity(t),pressure(t)]
[altitude (t+1),humidity(t+1),pressure(t+1)]
[altitude (t+2),humidity(t+2),pressure(t+2)]

And this sample's label is
[temperature(t+3)]

Next sample is the similar but obviously starts at t+1, and so on.
Note that I am doing data scaling (minmax) and train-test splitting.
The problem is that my model just predicts the mean value of all the temperature labels, so what am I doing wrong?

Does the train score go down at all? Try limiting the dataset to just a few samples (and keep the model simple initially) - the model should overfit and achieve a good train score. That would indicate the model is capable of learning. If the model can't memorise those few samples, it points to a major issue somewhere in the pipeline. Once you verify the model is able to learn, you can work back from there.

Good approach, I'll try it out, thank you
